# How do you detect an area that can be filled in in a bitmap in ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

I need to be able to detect a fill area for something similar to a coloring book picture. The user will click inside the area that needs to be filled. The image is user created bitmap content and so the fill area must be detected at runtime.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function myImage_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            myImage.imageDisplay.bitmapData.floodFill(event.localX,event.localY,0xFFFFFF);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image id="myImage" click="myImage_clickHandler(event)" source="/images/square.gif"/>
```

Comment: BTW funny name, just gotta get it up to 88 and that flux capacitor has to be fully charged and your ready to go 1.21 jigawatts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#floodFill%28%29

mouseX and mouseY are always the mouse position add a click listener to whatever object and just use the mouseX/mouseY or else the MouseEvent's event.localX and event.localY for the object that the listener is attached to

```
<mx:Image id="myImage" click="(myImage.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.floodFill(event.localX,event.localY,0xFFFFFF)" source="http://www.carolynsbloomingcreations.com/images/square.gif"/>
```

Here's a solution if you use the Flex 4.5 Hero framework otherwise I was unable to get a handle on the bitmapData through the BitmapImage, the above solution also still works with Flex 3 or 4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <!--
    <mx:Image
        id="myImage"
        click="(myImage.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.floodFill(event.localX,event.localY,0xFFFFFF)"
        source="http://www.carolynsbloomingcreations.com/images/square.gif"/>
    -->
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace('test');
                var tempData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myBitmapImage.width,myBitmapImage.height);
                tempData = myBitmapImage.bitmapData;

                var localPoint:Point = container.globalToLocal(new Point(mouseX,mouseY));
                tempData.floodFill(localPoint.x,localPoint.y,0xFFFFFFFF);
                myBitmapImage.source = tempData;
                trace(localPoint.x + ":" + localPoint.y);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Group
        id="container"
        click="handleClick(event)">
        <s:BitmapImage
            id="myBitmapImage"
            source="@Embed('square.gif')" />
    </s:Group>


</s:Application>
```

even though they exposed the bitmapData in the 4.5 framework it's read only though so I had to copy it and re-assign it to the source that seemed to work

Comment: great scott! the answer to my prayers! i have to ask is there a chance this does not work with spark image component? i must use flex 4. i have pasted the code i am using above.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Spark Image has bitmapData as it's content, let me try it out, compiled in Flex 4 but using an mx:Image one minute.

Comment: Okay just played around with it some and what I found is there's _bitmapData as a private variable within s:BitmapImage but it's not accessible in the 4.0 version according to the docs it's exposed in the Hero SDK so I'm grabbing that now and trying... the above also works in 4.0 though

Comment: Thanks Shaun! I would vote up your answer but SO says I need 15 credits?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts, great no problem karma will have to do for now :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I'm trying to do!